# Am I high? Room owners can edit message that they moved posts?

Tags: bug, chat

What on earth?

Why are these message, these audit trail message, allowed to be edited? It's just nuts!

If they are important enough to be added to transcript, why can they be hidden? Yes I know that you *can* look at the history of that post, but come on now, that is half arsed excused.

I am not asking this as feature requests to make them not editable, I am reporting this as a Samuel L Jackson style mother (better judgment stepped in) bug!

These messages MUST be added to the transcript via the 'feeds' user! It is not trivials information that can be allowed to be just glossed over.

Comment: @AnnaLear this is not a duplicate of that question, that question is a feature request. This is a bug. Completely different question! Also, to close as dupe, it should have a question with an ACCEPTED answer.

Comment: Not on Meta. Meta is, as always, different

Comment: Calling this a feature-request or a bug is a matter of semantics. Both your question and the other one are asking for the exact same thing in the end. Only closing duplicate requests when the original has been resolved makes no sense on meta - not everything can be fixed or even responded to right away, so why keep dupes around in the meantime?